# Make multiple if statements into short statements

Tags: c#, .net, if-statement

I am trying to make a comma-separated `string` based on `boolean` properties value in the `model`.

**Code**

```
        string options = string.Empty;

        if (model.Fruits.Value)
        {
            options += "FR,";
        }
        if (model.Drinks.Value)
        {
            options += "DR,";
        }
        if (model.Lunch.Value)
        {
            options += "LU,";
        }
        if (model.Dinner.Value)
        {
            options += "DI,";
        }
```

Can we make above code to be shorthand based, using `ternary conditional operator (?:)` or should I just leave the above one as it is, because it's more readable ?

Any suggestions would be great.

Comment: use switch or dictionary search.

Comment: like Tazbir said, i would use a switch

Comment: Yes you can make it shorter using ternary operators within a single concatenation statement. Whether you _should_ is entirely a matter of opinion for you and how you like to structure your code.

Comment: btw, it looks like: by writing options+= youa are trying to build a string. for that switch won't work though.

Comment: @TazbirBhuiyan look carefully, the if statement conditions are not mutually exclusive. `switch` would not work here for that reason, and also because it generally can't deal with multiple different input values.

Comment: @sLw look carefully, the if statement conditions are not mutually exclusive. `switch` would not work here for that reason, and also because it generally can't deal with multiple different input values.

Comment: why are you asking? Seems pretty straight-forward to me.

Comment: NO, you can't use a `switch` here. You are better off with what you have currently

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . What are you going to **do** with `options`?

Comment: another option would be to pu `FR` directly into the `Fruits` object and have in `model` a `List<BaseItems> allOptions` then you can make filter it in linq

Comment: @mjwills , Not I guess!,  I tried to find whether I can use `ternary conditional operator (?:)`, In the comments I came to know that the code which i wrote is the way to go.

Comment: @MongZhu , Good idea but unfortunately Fruits is a `boolean` value.

Comment: do you think that it might happen that you will extend your options one day? say with `Dessert` ? or `Cocktails` ?

Comment: @MongZhu , We have max 6 options and that's fixed.

Comment: Then make a small wrapper around it, or use a dictionary

Comment: "I tried to find whether I can use ternary conditional operator (?:), In the comments I came to know that the code which i wrote is the way to go." . Not necessarily. You can use it as-is or you can use ternary operators. Either is fine. It's up to you. Neither way is definitively "best". As I said earlier, it depends on what style you prefer.

Comment: ok, it was just a suggestion. you code looks very readable. I personally would go with the list approach. it is extensible

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There may be *some* advantages to an approach like:

```
    string options = 
        (model.Fruits.Value ? "FR," : "")
        + (model.Drinks.Value ? "DR," : "")
        + (model.Lunch.Value ? "LU," : "")
        + (model.Dinner.Value ? "DI," : "");
```

Specifically, this will be a single call to `string.Concat` (see [example here](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgtghgzgLgpgJwDQxASwDYB8ACAGAAhwEYA6AJQFcA7GNMOUgYQHswAHTRAZUQDc0AYzhQA3AFgAUDgBMBAApSA3lIJqixQgHE4MAPLs6LalAAUASlXqVk9XY2EWhtMagEAvASv37psCwATOAxSADEESjQYKFIANQgMSjgCAH4CACJQ8iR0ghAM9MtbH3sAagI/QODSABEENGoAaxj4xOS09Jrs3Pz0wu8StXLKoJCAGRpBAAs4hKTUjLGAVRy8gqLBu2H/UdqG6kRZtoXOgElV3sKJYp8BuxwAdgInIxNruwBfAYGAWSqMAg7YLvdSyAh/UYDGyDHAAZgIwBYLAwaXCkWiSAIdQazUxE2o00xNX2iBBai+kg+QA==) - you're looking for a single `call string [mscorlib]System.String::Concat(string, string, string, string)`), so it will avoid lots of intermediate strings (`+=`) in the "all options" scenario. However, frankly I would advise using a `[Flags] enum` instead, i.e.

```
[Flags]
enum FoodOptions {
    None = 0,
    Fruits = 1,
    Drinks = 2,
    Lunch = 4,
    Dinner = 8,
}

var options = FoodOptions.None;
if(model.Fruits.Value) options |= FoodOptions.Fruits;
if(model.Drinks.Value) options |= FoodOptions.Drinks;
if(model.Lunch.Value) options |= FoodOptions.Lunch;
if(model.Dinner.Value) options |= FoodOptions.Dinner;
```

which is just integers throughout.

Comment: Thanks, `ternary operator` worked well, I would like to know I have 6 options to check, so for code readability using `ternary operator` is good or simple `if` statements?

Answer (score 0):

a little upgrade to your code. thought it might might help you..

```
using System;
using System.Text;

public class Program
{
public static void Main()
{
       StringBuilder options = new StringBuilder();
    Food model= new Food();


    if (model.Fruits.HasValue)
    {
        options.Append("FR,");
    }
    if (model.Drinks.HasValue)
    {
        options.Append("DR,");
    }
    if (model.Lunch.HasValue)
    {

        options.Append("LU,");
    }
    if (model.Dinner.HasValue)
    {
        options.Append("DI,");
    }
    Console.WriteLine(options);
}
}

public class Food{
public int? Fruits{get;set;}
public int? Drinks{get;set;}
public int? Lunch{get;set;}
public int? Dinner{get;set;}

public Food(){
    Fruits=1;
    Drinks=null;
    Lunch=2;
    Dinner=3;
}

}
```